# Page load errors due to missing this.setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error when I populate my form with stored data. My form contains an array so I'm using `{this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition)` to create a loop. The error comes from `{careerHistoryPosition.errors['company']`. This part of the form, is related to `errors` when the form is submited and I don't store this in the database so when the form is populated, errors isn't set. I assume it's to do with `this.setState` looking for something that doesn't exist.

Snippet: `Constructor`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let uniqueId = moment().valueOf();
    const profileCandidateCollection = props.profileCandidate;
    const profileCandidateCollectionId = profileCandidateCollection._id;
    const careerHistoryPositions = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.careerHistoryPositions;

    this.state = {
      careerHistoryPositions: careerHistoryPositions || [
        {
          company: '',
          uniqueId: uniqueId,
          title: '',
          description: '',
          startDateMonth: '',
          startDateYear: '',
          startDateMonth: '',
          endDateYear: '',
          isCurrent: false,
          isDisabled: false,
          errors: {}
        }
      ],
      profileCandidateCollectionId: profileCandidateCollectionId || null
    };
  }
```

Snippet: `render`

```
{this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition) => (
  <div key={careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId} className="individual-position">
    <SingleInput xs={9} inputType={'text'} controlFunc={this.handleCompanyNameChange(careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId)} content={careerHistoryPosition.company} placeholder={'Company'} bsSize={null}/> 
    {careerHistoryPosition.errors['company']
      ? <Col sm={12} className="has-error">
          <span className="help-block custom-error">{careerHistoryPosition.errors['company']}</span>
        </Col>
      : ''}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Are u sending the profileCandidate prop?

Comment: Try `{(careerHistoryPosition.errors && careerHistoryPosition.errors.company) ? ... : ''}`

Comment: @AndrewLi, Legend! Can you explain that?

Comment: @bp123 It checks to make sure `errors` exists before accessing `errors.company` so it won't say 'can't access `company` of undefined'. Wrapping it in parentheses will make sure it's not interpreted incorrectly.